# Binding Flexslider to outside div?

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider

I was wondering if it's possible to bind Flexslider events with outside divs? I'm looking specifically for a way to bind an outside

or  to change based on what picture is being viewed (a description to be precise.)

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean, that you want a description of each slides to be placed outside the flexslider's container?

Comment: There are callbacks available to do more complex things. Look under the Advanced tab. http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: @TheYaXxE Yeah, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="slide-1.jpg" /><!-- Your image/slide -->
            <span>Description 1</span><!-- Your description -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="slide-2.jpg" /><!-- Your image/slide -->
            <span>Description 2</span><!-- Your description -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slides {
    position: relative;
}

.slides li span {
    width: 500px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: - 50px;
}
```

You can position the `slide li span`*(description)* where ever you want. Just change the positions of the element. If you want to place your description in relative to the `body`then remove `position: relatvie`from the `.slides`.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fx9hH/1/)

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a clean/lightweight approach and this seems perfect. I was wondering if it would still operate the same with the thumbnail slider?